# How match a css style text in C #

Tags: c#, css, regex, match

I meet problematical for "matcher" css style in a text.
I want to get the following style:

**style Search**

```
<a id="d325" style="color: #ffffff;"> Visio Infrastructure and Applications </ a>
```

**Regex Used:**

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"<a id=""d(.+?)"" style=""(.+)"" ><\/a>");
```

I think the problem is `style = "color: # fffff"` but I just can not understand .

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look at this for getting info out of your html. https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems with your regex are

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"<a id=""d(.+?)"" style=""(.+)"" ><\/a>");
                                                           ^         no space in the string
                                                             ^       the text between the tags is not matched
                                                                ^    there is a space in the string
```

The other question is, is a regex the right tool for this job?

Comment: Strong agreement on the last part. Use an HTML parsing library to parse HTML. There are plenty out there

Comment: 1:no space in the string ? what do you mean by that?

Comment: @MehdiBugnard, your regex requires a space at this point, but in the string you want to match there is no space at this point, so the regex can not match-

Comment: yess you are right !! this regex is better -> Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"<a id=""d(.+?)"" style=""(.+)"">.(.+?)<\/ a>"); ?

Answer (score 0):

From my side, you just forget the whitespace in your regex with this one

```
<a\sid="d(.+?)"\sstyle="(.+)">.*?</a>
```

you've got the result : **325** and **color: #ffffff**;

Is the result you want ?